# Java Draw Image From Byte Array

Tags: java, netbeans, bitmap

I am trying to read data from the serial port and convert it into a picture. The code builds but nothing is displayed. Does anyone see anything obvious I am missing?

```
int len = 0;
while ( ( data = in.read()) > -1 )
{
    if ( data == '\n' ) {                       
        break;
    }
    buffer[len++] = (byte) data;
}
InputStream inPic = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(inPic);
Graphics img1 = img.createGraphics();
img1.drawImage(img, 0, 0,null);
```

Comment: is the length of buffer exactly the length of your image data?  and why are you using a newline as the end of data?  what type of image data are you working with?

Comment: Your assuming newlines aren't found in the image data. This is untrue

Comment: an image can have so many '\n' in its body

Comment: I see what you are saying. Can you think of a way i can load the array then?